# NativeScript with or without angular has same performance?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

About performance, has any difference if I write my app using NativeScript with Angular or NativeScript without Angular? In both case the performance is same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats a good question!

In theory, you can achieve same performance with Nativescript + JavaScript/Typescript combo as compared to Nativescript + Angular. But wait.

To achieve that, you will have to write tons of fine code to handle things like routing, dependency management, etc, which Angular handles for you effectively (with years of refinement from Angular team and tons of Open source community contributes) Bottom line, you can achieve the same with with lots of additional effort, which you make a call based on your need. This is one main reason, why most developers choose some framework(be it Angular, React, Vue.js) to **speedup the development and to achieve good results.(In terms of maintainability, performance, etc)**

When you choose Nativescript + JS(and not Typescript which you mostly tend to choose for Angular) you loose the advantage of Typescript(like strong typing, ECMAScript 6 support out of the box).

Here are some links which talks about advantage of using the framework,

https://www.techseria.com/top-5-benefits-angularjs-2-0/

https://www.cleveroad.com/blog/react-vs-angular-ultimate-performance-research-2017

And when you consider seed project [like this](https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced), you can setup an amazing base for your project which shares good portion of your code between multiple platforms and you also get fine tuned out of the box commands to build, debug, deploy, etc.

Will be happy to know if you have any perspective on why not to choose a framework.. Angular in this case.

Answer (score 0):

@anand, Thanks for your answer. When I started with NativeScript, Angular was not that popular for this platform, and I'm not particularly a fan of this framework so over time I did not adopt this framework. But now I see a big growth of it with NativeScvript. In terms of productivity I work with coffescript and I already have a design pattern to be followed, with a lot ready, where I can reap a lot of the stuff I build. My question is in relation to application execution peformance, since in my view, when I use javascript and the nativescript api directly, I do not have the Angular layer between the parts, so this would mean that at least the performance would be the same .

I do not understand when you say that the routes or the dependencies' management of the Angular are more faster, this is due to some special treatment given the routes or dependencies managed by the angular? For example, page navigation (routing) on NS is very simple:

```
var topmost = frame.topmost()
var topmost.navigate({
  moduleName: "views/mypage/mypage"
})
```

How Angular can do better or most simple or most fast?

I have searched in official documentation something about this question, about performance of app execution and not about productivity. But I'm not found any mention that NS with Angular is more faster that NS without Angular, out productivity question.

https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-is-how-you-build-native-mobile-apps-with-angular

Thanks again!